# Using change table tracking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to use the changed table tracking feature of sql server 2008. I have enabled this on many tables. Now i have to write a sync program to transfer this data to another location.
 My problem is how do i get only those tables whose data has changed without having to loop through all the changed tables list and checking each of them?

Comment: Have changed since when? Since the last time you ran such a read-only query that doesn't record that it read the change tables?

Comment: i can get all the commited transactions using this query SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_commit_table . But the problem i face now is i cant find a link to the tables..i need to know which trasaction id is linked to which table.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401801/using-changetable-on-all-tables)?

Comment: please help any one !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try `sys.CHANGE_TRACKING_TABLES` (documented [on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895362.aspx)).

You'll have to use `OBJECT_NAME` to get the table name from the first column.